# How do I manually save in Battlefield 4?

Tags: battlefield-4, ps4

How to save battlefield 4 game progress manually on PS4? I want to save the game at any point in the progress rather than waiting for the autosave feature to kick in.

Comment: You can't the game doesn't have this feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The progress mechanism of BF4 is depending on savepoints. The player can not induce saving the progress at any time. You can think of it what you want, but Dice does not give you the liberty to save after every corner.

Comment: This is such a stupid game. Thank god I bought this game for 14 bucks almost 7 months after it was released. I have read the frustration of the gamers who purchased this game at an expensive price and couldnt save their game progress and also lost their progress in some cases. Why in the world wouldnt they give this manual save feature? Seems like DICE have that bad game programmers ! what a shame

Comment: Nah! BF4 is a multiplayer game! The singleplayerpart is just mandatory but not essential. BF4 often gets compared with COD and if you are talking about SP, COD wins 100%. But the MP of BF4 is awesome and has a lot of content, possibilitys and fun. Your comment is evaluating a fish by its abillity to climb a tree.

Comment: I agree to what you say. I was saying from the consumer standpoint that If i as a consumer buy a game then I expect it to be bug free and and have important features like saving the game manually inbuilt within it. This game has a lot of bugs and I cant tell me the number of times I had to restart certain mission because of the bugs in the game. Just look up for BF4 save game bug ot the dam jump bug. I am in state where I would prefer COD 1000 times over BF4 now.

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as correct.

Comment: @Raghu Many gamees goes by the autosave or set save places system. As in the challenge decreases in many games if you would be allowed to save every 1m you go. For example deadspace only allow saving at save stations